# Options distributing an .IPA file to our customers - (Rejected on App Store)

Tags: ios, xcode

One of our customers uses an app (developed by a third-party - not by us or the customer) which they simply install via a web page.
From what we can see its an .ipa build with a manifest.plist file.

However, our customer insists:

- that they don't have an Enterprise Developer account
- that they don't hand over any UDIDs when they need to install the IPA on a new device

**Have we overlooked some way to distribute the app via an .ipa file? (We're new to iOS development so this is entirely possible)**

Background info:
We've created a "companion" iOS app which basically just takes text input from the user and saves it to an API running on a LAN PC.
The app was rejected by the Apple reviews team because our "app is not appropriate for the App Store since it is designed specifically for business clients"
They have suggested releasing it via the Volume Purchase Program.

This sounds fine in principle, but it requires our customers to create brand new Volume Purchasing Accounts - apparently their existing account on the iPads can't be converted/upgraded to VP accounts.
Our main customer is not willing to do this and is asking why we can't make it as simple as their other app... Which is an understandable point of view.

Obviously we're trying to play by the rules, but I believe the other app is probably doing it "illegally". **Any suggestions on achieving this while staying the right side of the Apple Police, would be very much appreciated.**

Comment: They could be using a service like https://www.diawi.com/   but the costs for their enterprise plan are significantly more than the Apple enterprise developer program. To use VPP the end customer really needs to be using an MDM (and to be honest if they own the devices they should be anyway). Then a single Apple ID is used to enroll in the VPP and the app is made available via the MDM platform. The individual device users do not need to enroll in VPP.  For smaller fleets there are free and low cost MDM solutions from managenegine and Cisco meraki

Comment: If you are going to supply this companion app to multiple (of your) customers then VPP is the way to go. If it is specific to this one customer then you could use VPP or enterprise membership. The downside of VPP is that you need to use MDM or the Apple Configurator to load the app to the devices. The downside of enterprise membership is that it has an annual cost.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Paul - I did read about MDMs last night whilst looking for an answer. This is a fixed cost job and we didn't expect to have to pay for anything over the cost of our standard Apple Developer Licence, so we'll have a look at the free MDMs. I suppose I was hoping for a simpler route for our customer to stop them asking why we are making their lives so much harder than their other supplier!

Comment: Strictly speaking, the MDM is their responsibility, not yours.  You wouldn't want to be responsible for managing their devices.  As I said, if they own iOS devices then they really should be using an MDM anyway; As well as enabling them to push apps to the device (so the user doesn't even need to install the app), it lets them control policies on the devices, remote wipe the devices and remove passcodes; this can be very useful if an employee leaves without providing the passcode for the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t overlooked anything. Your customer is mistaken. Apple doesn’t allow the kind of distribution they describe because it would be too easy for developers to bypass the App Store, and Apple doesn’t want that.

You can investigate further by opening up the IPA. It’s just a zip archive with a different extension. Find the provisioning profile file. It’s binary but parts of it are XML, which you can see if you open it in a text editor. An ad hoc build will list the device IDs of all the devices the app can be installed on.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I was afraid that would be the case. Interesting about the zip archive - we hadn't spotted that. Our ad-hoc builds shows our Apple UDIDs. The other app shows **ProvisionsAllDevices**. I'm guessing that means they are using their Enterprise License and just sticking it out there on a web page for anyone to download.